# WebRTC: ICE failed, add a TURN server and see about:webrtc for more details

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I'm trying to make a simple connection, but run into the error which is the title of this post.

My code for the caller and answerer are below:

**STUN Server**

```
const servers = {iceServers: [{urls: ['stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302']}]}
```

**Peer A (Caller)**

```
let peer = new RTCPeerConnection(servers)
let chnl = peer.createDataChannel("channel")
chnl.onopen = e => console.log("Connection opened")
chnl.onmessage = e => console.log("New message: " + e.data)
peer.onicecandidate = e => console.log(JSON.stringify(e.candidate))
peer.createOffer().then(offer => peer.setLocalDescription(offer)).then(a => console.log(peer.localDescription))
```

**Peer B (Answerer)**

```
let peer = new RTCPeerConnection(servers)
peer.ondatachannel= e => {
    peer.chnl = e.channel
    peer.chnl.onopen = e => console.log("Connection opened")
    peer.chnl.onmessage = e => console.log("New message: " + e.data)
}
peer.onicecandidate = e => console.log(JSON.stringify(e.candidate))
peer.setRemoteDescription(offer)
peer.createAnswer().then(answer=> peer.setLocalDescription(answer)).then(a => console.log(peer.localDescription))
```

I was running this code in 2 separate tabs of Firefox's console. I would copy the offer and answer logged from the `onicecandidate` callback and set these as the answerer's and caller's remote descriptions, respectively. At this moment, I would receive the error: `WebRTC: ICE failed, add a TURN server and see about:webrtc for more details`. I'm unsure how to resolve this.

Thank you

Comment: As the error message asks you to add the TURN server, you can google to search the TURN server list and then try to add it to the `servers` variable and test.